# Get last item added in a BindlingList

Tags: c#

I have a BindingList variable and I need to get the last item that was added to it.  The following code works, but I'd like to know if there's a better way or something that I'm missing:

```
WorkoutScheduleList[WorkoutScheduleList.IndexOf(WorkoutScheduleList[(WorkoutScheduleList.Count - 1)])].WorkoutScheduleID);
```

It's not the easiest to read, but it basically takes the count of the list and subtracts 1 from it, and uses that for the IndexOf method to get the last item that was added to the list.

Comment: Something like `WorkoutScheduleList.Last()`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking...something more "readable" than what I have now.

Comment: You should be all set then. [Documentation for `Last()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the [ListChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms132742) event of the binding list, and keep a reference of the item that was added.

Example:

```
class Program
{
    static object last_item;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BindingList<object> WorkoutScheduleList = new BindingList<object>();

        WorkoutScheduleList.ListChanged += (s, e) => {
            if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemAdded)
                last_item = WorkoutScheduleList[e.NewIndex];
        };

        WorkoutScheduleList.Add("Foo");
        WorkoutScheduleList.Add("Bar");
        WorkoutScheduleList.Insert(1, "FooBar");

        //prints FooBar
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("last item added: {0}", last_item));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastItem = WorkoutScheduleList[WorkoutScheduleList.Count - 1].WorkoutScheduleID;
```

or using LinQ

```
var lastLinqItem = WorkoutScheduleList.Last().WorkoutScheduleID;
```

Comment: This will work for items added with the Add method, not with items added with the Insert, InsertItem or indexer set methods.